# Android - PendingIntent not getting called

Tags: android, geolocation, android-pendingintent, android-location

I am new to android, and I have been sitting here for 4 hours trying to solve this problem to no avail.

The module is running on independent app, but when  merging with the main app, it is not working.

The code is not reaching the SendMessage function, hence it is not sending the location to the server. Can you state the error?

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  service = new LocationService(this);
  sessionProcessor = new SessionProcessor(getApplicationContext());
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  BroadcastLocationService.enabled = true;
  Log.d("Home","A");
  service.getLocation();
  Log.d("Home","B");
}
```

BroadcastLocationService.java

```
public class BroadcastLocationService extends IntentService {
  public static boolean enabled = false;
  SessionProcessor sessionProcessor;
  HashMap<String, String> hashMapAddTrack;
  String responseAddTrack;

  public BroadcastLocationService() {
    super("BroadcastLocationService");
  }

  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.d("BroadCast","A");
    sendMessage(getApplicationContext(), new LocationService(getApplicationContext()).getLocation());
    Log.d("BroadCast","B");
  }

  private void sendMessage(Context mContext, Location location) {
    Log.d("BroadCast","C");
    Log.d("Latitude",String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
    Log.d("Longitude",String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
    hashMapAddTrack = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hashMapAddTrack.put("latitude", String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
          hashMapAddTrack.put("longitude",String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
    APICommunication apiCommunication = new APICommunication();
    try {
      HashMap<String, String> header = new HashMap<String, String>();
      String token = "Token:" + sessionProcessor.getSessionId();
      header.put("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(token.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
      responseAddTrack = apiCommunication.getResponseString(new CommonVariables().URL + "addTracking.php", hashMapAddTrack, header);

    } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

LocationService.java

```
public class LocationService {

   private Context mContext;
   private Location mLocation;
   private LocationManager locationManager;
   private PendingIntent intent;

   public LocationService(Context context) {
     mContext = context;

     Intent smsIntent = new Intent(mContext, BroadcastLocationService.class);
     intent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, smsIntent, 0);
   }


   public void cancelUpdates() {
      if(locationManager != null) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(intent);
      }
   }

   public Location getLocation() {
   locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

   boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
   boolean isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
   Log.d("LocationService","A");
   if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
      showSettingsDialog();
   } else {
     if (isGPSEnabled) {
     try {
       Log.d("LocationService","B");
       locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
       LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
       0 * 1000 * 60,
       0,
       intent);

      if(mLocation == null) {
        mLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
       }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
       showSettingsDialog();
    }
 } else {
   try {
     Intent smsIntent = new Intent(mContext, BroadcastLocationService.class);
     PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, smsIntent, 0);

     locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
     LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
     0* 1000 * 60,
     0,
     intent);
     if(mLocation == null) {
        mLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
     }
  } catch (SecurityException e) {
   showSettingsDialog();
  }
 }
}

return mLocation;
```

}
Log on other app (How it should be)

```
    D/Home: A
    D/LocationService: A
    D/LocationService: B
    D/LocationService: C
    D/Home: B
    V/TextView: stopSelectionActionMode()
    V/TextView: stopSelectionActionMode()
    V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4 ,Parent =null, this =com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{3864af2d I.E..... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
    D/OpenGLRenderer: initialize DisplayEventReceiver 0x55c03c0960
    D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: false
    D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x55c03c56e0) (w:1728 h:1984 s:1728 f:0x1 u:0x000100)
    D/Atlas: Validating map...
    D/ViewRootImpl: hardware acceleration is enabled, this = ViewRoot{35c34933 com.example2.myloc/com.example2.myloc.HomeActivity,ident = 0}
    V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0 ,Parent =ViewRoot{35c34933 com.example2.myloc/com.example2.myloc.HomeActivity,ident = 0}, this =com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{3864af2d V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
    D/ActivityThread: SVC-Calling onStartCommand: com.example2.myloc.BroadcastLocationService@11bf5cee, flags=0, startId=1
    D/BroadCast: A
    D/ActivityThread: SVC-Calling onStartCommand: com.example2.myloc.BroadcastLocationService@11bf5cee, flags=0, startId=2
    D/LocationService: A
    D/LocationService: B
    D/LocationService: C
    D/BroadCast: C
    D/Latitude: 25.304425
    D/Longitude: 82.97385000000001
    D/BroadCast: B
    D/BroadCast: A
    D/LocationService: A
    D/LocationService: B
    D/LocationService: C
    D/BroadCast: C
    D/Latitude: 25.304425
    D/Longitude: 82.97385000000001
    D/BroadCast: B
```

Log on this app:

```
    D/Home: A
    D/LocationService: A
    D/LocationService: B
    D/LocationService: C
    D/Home: B
    D/skia: jpeg_decoder mode 1, colorType 4, w 225, h 225, sample 1, bsLength 146b!!
    D/skia: jpeg_decoder finish successfully, L:1843!!!
    V/ActivityThread: Performing resume of ActivityRecord{22c5c9ed token=android.os.BinderProxy@2c0b6022 {com.example2.project2/com.example2.project2.MainActivity}}
    D/ActivityThread: ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{22c5c9ed token=android.os.BinderProxy@2c0b6022 {com.example2.project2/com.example2.project2.MainActivity}}
    V/ActivityThread: Resume ActivityRecord{22c5c9ed token=android.os.BinderProxy@2c0b6022 {com.example2.project2/com.example2.project2.MainActivity}} started activity: false, hideForNow: false, finished: false
    V/ActivityThread: Resuming ActivityRecord{22c5c9ed token=android.os.BinderProxy@2c0b6022 {com.example2.project2/com.example2.project2.MainActivity}} with isForward=true
    V/ActivityThread: Scheduling idle handler for ActivityRecord{22c5c9ed token=android.os.BinderProxy@2c0b6022 {com.example2.project2/com.example2.project2.MainActivity}}
    D/ActivityThread: ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{22c5c9ed token=android.os.BinderProxy@2c0b6022 {com.example2.project2/com.example2.project2.MainActivity}}
    V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4 ,Parent =null, this =com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{24670355 I.E..... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
    D/OpenGLRenderer: initialize DisplayEventReceiver 0x55c0168b70
    D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: false
    D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x55c03e7230) (w:1728 h:1984 s:1728 f:0x1 u:0x000100)
    D/Atlas: Validating map...
    D/ViewRootImpl: hardware acceleration is enabled, this = ViewRoot{2eb3aa55 com.example2.project2/com.example2.project2.MainActivity,ident = 0}
    V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0 ,Parent =ViewRoot{2eb3aa55 com.example2.project2/com.example2.project2.MainActivity,ident = 0}, this =com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{24670355 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
    D/ListView: measureHeightOfChildren adapter = com.example2.project2.DrawerListAdapter@1a07cf0d, startPosition = 0, endPosition = 7, maxHeight = 1677, this = android.widget.ListView{3c7b0484 VFED.VC. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0c006b app:id/navList}
    D/OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0x55c03e5b10 initialize 0x55c041b1f0
    D/AbsListView: onSizeChanged w=720, h=1677, oldw=0, oldh=0, getChildCount=0, mSyncPosition=0, mNeedSync=false, mSyncMode=0, mAdaptercom.example2.project2.DrawerListAdapter@1a07cf0d, this=android.widget.ListView{3c7b0484 VFED.VC. ......I. 0,0-720,1677 #7f0c006b app:id/navList}, callstack=android.widget.ListView.onSizeChanged:1146 android.view.View.sizeChange:16180 android.view.View.setFrame:16145 android.widget.AbsListView.setFrame:2263 android.view.View.layout:16036 android.view.ViewGroup.layout:5181 android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout:1195 android.view.View.layout:16046 android.view.ViewGroup.layout:5181 android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout:1217
    E/GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)
    I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
    D/MALI: eglCreateContext:206: [MALI] eglCreateContext display 0x55c0155440, share context 0x0 here.
    D/MALI: gles_context_new:248: Create GLES ctx 0x7f5fe83018 successfully
    D/MALI: eglCreateContext:543: [MALI] eglCreateContext end. Created context 0x55c0451b00 here.
            I/OpenGLRenderer: Initializing program atlas...
    D/ProgramBinary/Service: BpProgramBinaryService.getFileDescriptor
    D/ProgramBinary/Service: BpProgramBinaryService.getProgramMapLen
    D/ProgramBinary/Service: BpProgramBinaryService.getProgramMapArray
    D/ProgramBinary/Service: BpProgramBinaryService.getProgramBinaryLen
    I/OpenGLRenderer: Program binary detail: Binary length is 121028, program map length is 112.
            I/OpenGLRenderer: Succeeded to mmap program binaries. File descriptor is 46, and path is /dev/ashmema.
    I/OpenGLRenderer: No need to use file discriptor anymore, close fd(46).
            D/OpenGLRenderer: TaskManager() 0x55c04f02d8, cpu = 8, thread = 4
    D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
    D/ListView: mSelectorRect.setEmpty in layoutChildren this=android.widget.ListView{3c7b0484 VFED.VC. ......ID 0,0-720,1677 #7f0c006b app:id/navList}
    D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x55c041b1e0,api=1)
    D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000
    D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x55c041b1e0)
    D/OpenGLRenderer: [TaskMgr] Running thread hwuiTask1 (28365)
    D/Surface: Surface::setBuffersDimensions(this=0x55c041b1e0,w=1080,h=1920)
    D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x55c05d8060) (w:1080 h:1920 s:1088 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
    W/MALI: glDrawArrays:714: [MALI] glDrawArrays takes more than 5ms here. Total elapse time(us): 8667
    D/AbsListView: onWindowFocusChanged: hasWindowFocus=true, this=android.widget.ListView{3c7b0484 VFED.VC. ......ID 0,0-720,1677 #7f0c006b app:id/navList}
    V/InputMethodManager: onWindowFocus: android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout{3fb2a424 VFE..... .F....I. 0,0-1080,1677 #7f0c0039 app:id/drawerLayout} softInputMode=288 first=true flags=#81810100
    V/InputMethodManager: START INPUT: android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout{3fb2a424 VFE..... .F....I. 0,0-1080,1677 #7f0c0039 app:id/drawerLayout} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@25a6e7f7 controlFlags=#105
    D/ListView: measureHeightOfChildren adapter = com.example2.project2.DrawerListAdapter@1a07cf0d, startPosition = 0, endPosition = 7, maxHeight = 1677, this = android.widget.ListView{3c7b0484 VFED.VC. ......ID 0,0-720,1677 #7f0c006b app:id/navList}
    D/ListView: mSelectorRect.setEmpty in layoutChildren this=android.widget.ListView{3c7b0484 VFED.VC. ......ID 0,0-720,1677 #7f0c006b app:id/navList}
    D/Surface: Surface::setBuffersDimensions(this=0x55c041b1e0,w=1080,h=1920)
    D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x55c0560170) (w:1080 h:1920 s:1088 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
    W/MALI: glDrawArrays:714: [MALI] glDrawArrays takes more than 5ms here. Total elapse time(us): 46167
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example2.project2">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="com.example2.project2.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example2.project2.LoginActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please ident your code, [make your question easy to read](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it will invite people to help you out more easily. Also provide the logcat you get in order to try and spot your error.

Comment: There is no error as such, but the SendMessage() is not getting called, which is getting called on the independent app before merging the code into this one.
Following is the comment flow.

Comment: I know there is no error as such, but if you post the logcat, we will see where your app reaches, and we will be able to **spot** your error/mistake or understand why your code doesn't seem to reach where you expect it to.

Comment: Added the log of both apps.

Comment: Post the manifest as well, please.

Comment: Added manifest.